# CGAL EXception raised

Tags: assertion, cgal, triangulation, delaunay

I´m working on on a program that perform a CDT in a set of points. After I have inserted   a lot of constraints CGAL raise the folowing exception:

0x0000022b9f34d7c0 "CGAL ERROR: assertion violation!\nExpr: is_finite(d)\nFile: C:\dev\CGAL-5.5.2\include\CGAL\MP_Float_impl.h\nLine: 70"

the code surounding the assertion is:

```
template < typename T >
    inline
    void MP_Float::construct_from_builtin_fp_type(T d)
    {
        if (d == 0)
          return;

    // Protection against rounding mode != nearest, and extended precision.
    Set_ieee_double_precision P;

    CGAL_assertion(is_finite(d));   //<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< here, this assertion

    // This is subtle, because ints are not symetric against 0.

    // First, scale d, and adjust exp accordingly.
    while (d <  INTERN_MP_FLOAT::trunc_min || d >  INTERN_MP_FLOAT::trunc_max) {
      ++exp;
      d /=  INTERN_MP_FLOAT::base;
    }
```

How to avoid this exception to happen?

Thanks

Comment: There is an infinite number somewhere. That's all we know. It's going to be hard to help you based on that information...

Comment: You will have to give us more of your code and data, so that we can help you with that issue.